# I'm getting this error "ReferenceError: responceBody is not defined"

Tags: postman

i have written my test script code like this

```
var responce=JSON.parse(responceBody);

tests["scope"] = responce.scope == "APP";
```

Comment: can anyone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your `responseBody` variable, try: `JSON.parse(responseBody)`

Comment: yes now it's working tq